# Block all outgoing network requests except SSH

Tags: ssh, networking, iptables

I have a type of linux that I only want to use for SSH to other machines. I'm trying to block outbound traffic to prevent auto-updates, viruses, etc.

I can use this to block all traffic except for those on the loopback interface going back into the localhost:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
```

Now how do I allow only SSH traffic out of this interface still? Just keeping port 22 open would be fine as well (non-specific to SSH protocol).

Will I be able to use an X server on the remote machine?

Comment: What distro are you using?

Comment: What have you tried? And yes, you will be able to tunnel X over SSH.

Comment: What about NTP or DNS?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a minimal iptables config:

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

This will allow to connect only by IP address.

In case you want to enable DNS resolutions add these two rules:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

If you know your DNS servers IP addresses, then it makes sense to allow connections only to them. Add to the above two commands `-d DNS_IP_ADDRESS`, e.g. `iptables -A OUTPUT -d 1.2.3.4 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT`

Comment: это полный пиздец. идите нахуй со своими iptables. бквально каждый блядский ответ ломает нахуй ssh соединение и отсылает меня в пизду в самое блять начало всех настроек. я где то с 3 раза догадался что не обязательно заново тратить час на настройку сервера и можно просто перезагрузить, потому что конченые пидорасы которые создавали эту хуйню (iptables) догадались добавить safeguard и после перезагрузки они сбрасываются если не сохранены коммитом. и тем не менее я проклинаю всех кто эту хуйню создавал и к ней причастен.